# Core Data and Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: core-data, grand-central-dispatch

Is it OK to use Core Data NSManagedObjects in a manner within GCD blocks where they don't interact, if I know that nothing else is going on (i.e. my program is only executing this GCD processing on the data at this point in time)?

Supposedly NSManagedObject is not ok to use with threads.  However it's vague to me.  It could be unsafe because of the faulting that occurs (so the data isn't actually immutable) - however, the faulting shouldn't affect other NSManagedObject data in memory.  Unless, the faulting in of data actually faults *out* other NSManagedObjects while I'm using them.  Would that happen?

To be more concrete, I'm talking about something like obtaining a set of all NSManagedObjects (NSNumbers) at a node of my Core Data object graph and adding 1 to each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure that (1) each thread/operation has its own unique managed object context and that (2) you eventually merge changes with all the other simultaneously active context.

It is quite common to have a background thread downloading data and putting it into Core Data while the foreground thread manages the UI. Each thread has its own context and they operate independently until the download is complete at which time the background context notifies the front thread context that it must merge the updated objects.

Comment: Please explain that in GCD terms, where I don't manage threads explicitly.  How can I know how many MOC's to have and how to work with them?

Comment: You initialize a context for each operation you create. You can think of each operation as its own little program. So, each little program needs its own context. See the concurrency part of the Core Data programming guide. That same principles apply to operations as are used by threads. The most important concept is that each individual context has no knowledge of the changes made by other context until it merges updates.

Comment: Does that mean every dispatch_async call should/must set up it's own managedObjectContext?